# It is not possible to use "present" as synonymous for "present-tense"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

When I try to use *present* as synonymous for *present-tense*, a dialog box informs me that *present* is used more times than *present-tense*. When I get the list of questions tagged with *present* the list shows no questions; it doesn't seem true that *present* is used more times than *present-tense.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't have any idea about the dialog box and why it says that, but I just went in and approved the `present` -> `present-tense` synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Odd, looks like it is already there in the suggested list, https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/present-tense/synonyms

Its just awaiting moderator intervention, or 3 votes.